# How to check for I/O errors when using "ifstream", "stringstream" and "rdbuf()" to read the content of a file to string?

Tags: c++, error-handling, io

I'm using the following method to read the content of a file into a string:

```
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();
std::string data(buffer.str());
```

But how do I check for I/O errors and ensure that all the content has actually been read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it the same way you would do it with any other insertion operation:

```
if (buffer << t.rdbuf())
{
    // succeeded
}
```

If either the extraction from `t.rdbuf()` or the insertion to `buffer` fails, `failbit` will be set on `buffer`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use t.good().
You can look description on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/

Answer (score 1):

`t.good()` was mentioned by bashor

Note though, that `t.good() != t.bad()`; You may want to use `!t.bad()` (or `!t.fail()`, `!t.eof()` for *specific* conditions)

I usually use

```
if (!t.bad())
{
     // go ahead if no _unpexpected errors

} 

if (!t.fail())
   t.clear(); // clear any _expected_ errors
```